# new project in pwa reurn "InvalidProjectName"

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ms-project-server-2016

I am trying to create a new project in PWA but i am receiving this error:
"ProjectNameInvalid".

here is my code:

```
projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaPath);
projContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, pass, domain);
ProjectCreationInformation newProj = new ProjectCreationInformation
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "1.1. سفارشات",
    Description = "تولید شده به صورت خودکار",
    Start = DateTime.Today.Date,
    EnterpriseProjectTypeId = GetEptUid("Enterprise Project")
};
PublishedProject newPublishedProj = projContext.Projects.Add(newProj);
QueueJob qJob = projContext.Projects.Update();
JobState jobState = projContext.WaitForQueue(qJob, timeoutSeconds);
```

> it is not because of persian characters, i created many projects
>   with persian characters before.

is there any standard format for Name? or any forbidden characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the periods are not allowed. Looking at [Project Server error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/project-server-error-codes), under the error code `GeneralInvalidCharacters = 20012` it says:

> Some characters are not valid. In addition to the TAB character, the
>   following characters are not valid in a project name: \ / " : ; < > |
>   , . ' ? * #